# Unresolved reference call.enqueue Error in Android Project using Kotlin and Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm new to android, I've an unresolved enqueue error in mainactivity.kt file. I'm using retrofit to retrieve data from
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

`Posts` Data Class

```
class Posts : ArrayList<PostsItem>()
```

`PostsItem` Data Class

```
data class PostsItem(
    val userId: Int,
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val body: String
)
```

`PostsService` Interface

```
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface PostsService {

    @GET("posts")
    fun getPosts() : Response<Posts>
}
```

`MainActivity.kt` file where I'm facing unresolved enqueue error

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
    val postsService = retrofit.create(PostsService::class.java)
    val call = postsService.getPosts()

    //IT SAYS UNRESOLVED REFERENCE enqueue
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<Posts>){
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Posts>, response: Response<Posts>){
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Posts>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to implement `onFailure()` method too:

```
call.enqueue(object : Callback<Posts> {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<Posts>, t: Throwable?) {
        // TODO implement me
    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<Posts>, response: Response<Posts>) {
        // TODO implement me
    }
})
```

Please check the Retrofit [documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Callback.html)

Also, change the interface as below:-

```
interface PostsService {

    @GET("posts")
    fun getPosts() : Call<Posts>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post, but it does not resolve the issue

Comment: You should use Posts instead of string I used

Comment: Updated with your class. please check

Comment: Yes I've used `Posts`

Comment: which retrofit version using?

Comment: implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'

Comment: please check now

Comment: I've done it, but now facing a new error https://ibb.co/1byJ6kt

Comment: It was a bracket issue, I found it, Thanks alot

Comment: Thanks. then accept my answer if it helps you. It will be helpful for others too

Answer (score 0):

There was a small error of `)` bracket in following line
`call.enqueue(object : Callback<Posts>){`

I am posting correct code here

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val postsService = retrofit.create(PostsService::class.java)


        val call: Call<Posts> = postsService.getPosts()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Posts> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Posts>, response: Response<Posts>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Posts>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        })
    }
}
```